# What does librdkafka.redist's logs mean

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, librdkafka

This is an extract from a console log relating to `Confluent.Kafka`'s `librdkafka.redist` dependency.

```
%3|1602097315.970|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-2| [thrd:kfkqaapq0002d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap]: kfkqaapq0002d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kfkqaapq0002d.ch.me.com:9092': No such host is known.  (after 42ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1602097315.970|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-3| [thrd:kfkqaapq0002d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap]: kfkqaapq0002d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kfkqaapq0002d.ch.me.com:9092': No such host is known.  (after 41ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1602097315.972|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kfkqaapq0003d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap]: kfkqaapq0003d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kfkqaapq0003d.ch.me.com:9092': No such host is known.  (after 48ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1602097315.973|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: rdkafka#producer-1: kfkqaapq0003d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kfkqaapq0003d.ch.me.com:9092': No such host is known.  (after 48ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1602097316.459|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kfkqaapq0001d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap]: kfkqaapq0001d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kfkqaapq0001d.ch.me.com:9092': No such host is known.  (after 42ms in state CONNECT)
```

I'm trying to understand what each pipe delimited section is. Can anybody tell me? I can't find any information on it. I assume the 2nd column is some sort of timestamp, the 3rd is a status and the 4th is an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns:

- `%3` - syslog severity level. Lower is more severe.
- `1602097315.970` - seconds since epoch.
- `rdkafka#consumer-2` - client instance name, which is a combination of the (possibly configured) `client.id`, the client type (consumer) and a running number that is increased (in the current process) for each new client instance.
- `[thrd:kfkqaapq0002d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap]` - what thread the log is emitted from. Application threads will be named `thrd:app`, all other thread names are librdkafka internal threads.
- `kfkqaapq0002d.ch.me.com:9092/bootstrap` - the broker the log message corresponds to.
- `Failed to resolve 'kfkqaapq0002d.ch.me.com:9092': No such host is known.  (after 42ms in state CONNECT)` - the log message itself.